# How do I parse JSON array in Swift when there is no key

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am using the following code in Swift Playground

```
import Foundation

struct PlayerInfo: Decodable{
    var PlayerID: String = ""
    var FirstName: String = ""
    var LastName: String = ""
}

var rosterRequest = PlayerRequest()

rosterRequest.loadPlayers()

class PlayerRequest{
    var players: [PlayerInfo] = []
    
    func loadPlayers(){

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/Players?key=<key>") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let mydata = data {
                print(mydata)
                
                if let players = try? JSONDecoder().decode([PlayerInfo].self, from: mydata){

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        for player in players{
                            print(player.LastName)
                            }
                        }
                        return
                }
                print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I know I get the data because it prints the length but when it come to parsing the data it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I run the request through Rested I get:

```
[
    {
        "PlayerID": 20000441,
        "SportsDataID": "",
        "Status": "Active",
       ...
    },
    {
        "PlayerID": 20000442,
        "SportsDataID": "",
        "Status": "Active",
        ...
    }
...
]
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't seem to have `FirstName` and `LastName` keys? Or have you omitted them? Anyway, don't print the `localizedDescription` or the error. `print(error)` if you actually want to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. PlayerID is an Int and I had it defined as a String